# Java class file spec - double and long representation

Tags: java, jvm, .class-file

In Java class file specification, at section about [long and double representation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se8/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.5), the document says:

> The CONSTANT_Long_info and CONSTANT_Double_info represent 8-byte
>   numeric (long and double) constants:

```
CONSTANT_Long_info {
    u1 tag;
    u4 high_bytes;
    u4 low_bytes;
}

CONSTANT_Double_info {
    u1 tag;
    u4 high_bytes;
    u4 low_bytes;
}
```

> All 8-byte constants take up two entries in the constant_pool table of
>   the class file. If a CONSTANT_Long_info or CONSTANT_Double_info
>   structure is the item in the constant_pool table at index n, then the
>   next usable item in the pool is located at index n+2. The
>   constant_pool index n+1 must be valid but is considered unusable.

My doubt is what the `tag` of entry in constant_pool in index `n+1`.

Comment: As it says, "must be valid but is considered unusable"; so, anything that's not a long or double.

Comment: If in `contant_pool` entry at index `n` a read 1 byte to `tag` and more 8 bytes to `high_bytes` and `low_bytes`, how many bytes I should read to the entry at index `n+1`?

Comment: None, it's unusable.

Answer (score 1):

There is no tag at index `n+1` because there is no constant pool entry at index `n+1`. It's just like index 0. There's no data for it and it skips straight to the next entry.

Answer (score 0):

By trial and error, and with help comment of [tassos-bassoukos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/397786/tassos-bassoukos), I reach a solution. When found a constant long or double at index `n`, **the index at `n+1` is not usd, only that**.

I will show with code:

```
List<Constant> constants = new ArrayList<>();
byte[] bytecode = ... // reads the class byte code
int constantPoolCount = getConstantPoolCount(bytecode);
int offset = getConstantPoolStartOffset(bytecode);

for(int i = 1; i < constantPoolCount; i++){
  int tag = bytecode[offset];
  offset++;

  if(tag == LONG_CONSTANT_TAG) {
    byte[] highBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytecode, offset, offset+4);
    offset += 4;
    byte[] lowBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(bytecode, offset, offset+4);
    offset += 4;

    ConstantLong c = new ConstantLong(highBytes, lowBytes);
    constants.add(c);

    // because we are at CONSTANT LONG, the entry at n+1 is not used
    constants.add(null);
    i++;

  } else if(tag == DOUBLE_CONSTANT_TAG) {
    ... // performs the same, like LONG_CONSTANT_TAG
  }

  // read more entries without skip indexes.

}
```

Note that `constants` list is indexed starting in zero, and entries in `constant_pool` bytecode is indexed starting in 1.